# node/add is breaking menu hierarchy

Tags: 7, routes, taxonomy-terms

I'm a newbie, and I'm trying to create a site on Drupal7.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary with many terms. Then I use taxonomy_menu and nice_menu to show the terms. This is working perfectly.

The problem comes when I create (or edit) a node (of any type) and I associate it to a term. The menu item(s) corresponding to selected(s) term(s) loses his place in hierarchy. Searching on database I realize the column "plid" on "menu_links" table is set to 0.

Searching on drupal.org I found [this](http://drupal.org/node/1081330) post, I think my problem is related to it. On first comment someone gives a solution, but I can't use it, because in this case nodes won't be shown in the menu.

ideas?

P.S.: sorry on my bad english, ask if you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be a known issue. Please see the below two issues for the taxonomy_menu project - the second contains a patch you could try?

http://drupal.org/node/1208484

http://drupal.org/node/1485198